# How to determine what CSP the Strong Name (sn.exe) tool is using?

Tags: c#, .net, code-signing, strongname

I recently got a Yubikey and started using it for ... well ... everything related to public/private key operations that I can.  Having, in the past, accidentally leaked my strong name keypair in a public git repo, I decided to set my projects up to use the `AssemblyKeyNameAttribute`, pointing it at the container name of my code signing key which is stored on the Yubikey (I documented the mess, [here](http://matthewdippel.blogspot.com/2017/09/howto-strong-name-sign-net-assembly.html) for anyone interested).

Because the keyset cannot be found by `sn.exe` when the CSP is set to the default value (I assume 'Microsoft Base Crypto Provider v1'), I have to execute `sn.exe -c "Microsoft Base Smart Card Crypto Provider"` at least once before I run a build.  To make matters worse, this has to be executed as an Administrator, but the key can only be retrieved as a non-elevated user, forcing me to write a [PowerShell script](https://gist.github.com/Diagonactic/8ab27b144149c28d1a15424d53c4f44a) which elevates in the pre-build to run that command.

The issue is that this elevates on *every build*, which is annoying.  I've also run into a circumstance where using a different version of `sn.exe` to reset the CSP (so I could generate a one-off public/private keypair for strong naming a library that was weak named, but that I didn't author), stopped the build's ability to find my key despite using that same version to set it *back* to the Smart Card CSP (I could break it with the wrong version, but could only fix it with a specific version).

I'd like to add a step to my script to look up *what* CSP is currently set so that it can skip elevating to change it if it doesn't need to and being able to get this information would also help me in troubleshooting this odd issue I had with `sn.exe` not switching back to the Smart Card provider.

Does anyone know how to get the value of the current CSP that `sn.exe`, `csc.exe` (and hopefully `ilasm.exe` and others) are configured to use?  Or, is there a way to specify the CSP to use for finding the key specified in `AssemblyKeyNameAttribute`, allowing me to skip all of this nonsense in the first place?